# How to create multiple servers each listening on different ports?

Tags: java, network-programming, p2p

I am new to network programming and trying to write code that can create multiple server sockets on different ports. I am creating a separate thread for each server. The server itself is multithreaded so that it can handle multiple clients. The servers.java file described below calls the multithreaded server-class defined in MultiEchoserver.java

```
//Server.java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.*;

public class Servers{
    public static int ports [] = {1234, 1235, 1236, 1237, 1238};

    String s = "server_";

    public static void main(String args[]){
       for(int i = 0; i <ports.length; i++){
            String s = "server_" + Integer.toString(i);
            MyRunnable serv = new MyRunnable(s, ports[i]);
            serv.start();
        //System.out.println("Server started " + s);
        }
    }


 }

class MyRunnable extends Thread{
 public static String s;
 public static int port;
 public MyRunnable(String s, int port){
    this.s = s;
    this.port = port;
}
public void run(){
    try{

        MultiEchoServer server = new MultiEchoServer(s, port);
        server.createServer();
        //server.start();
        System.out.println("HERE");

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


}
```

MultiEchoServer.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MultiEchoServer{
    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static String s; 
    private static int PORT;

public MultiEchoServer(String s, int port){
    this.s = s;
    this.PORT = port;
}

public void createServer(){
    try{
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println("Listening at port: " + PORT);
    }
    catch(IOException ioEx){
        System.out.println("\nUnable to set up port!");
        System.exit(1);
    }
   
    try{
    do{
        
            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("\nNew client accepted.\n");
            ClientHandler handler = new ClientHandler(client);

            handler.start();
        }while(true); 
    }
    catch(IOException ioEx){
        ioEx.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    }
}


class ClientHandler extends Thread{
 private Socket client;
 private Scanner input;
 private PrintWriter output;

 public ClientHandler(Socket socket){
    client = socket;
    
    try{
        input = new Scanner(client.getInputStream());
        output = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
    }
    catch(IOException ioEx){
        ioEx.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void run(){
    String received;
    
    do{
        received = input.nextLine();
        
        output.println("ECHO: " + received);
        
        
    }while(!received.equals("QUIT"));
           
    try{
        if(client != null){
            System.out.println("Closing down connection");
            client.close();
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ioEx){
        System.out.println("Unable to disconnect");
    }
}
```

}

The code works when I am initializing one server instance. However, when a whole array of port numbers is passed, then only the server listening on the last port is initialized while for others I get the 'Unable to set up' message. All port numbers are valid.

Comment: Please print out the stacktrace for that exception and show it to us.  The most likely explanation is that you have bound to the same port in another thread.  (Possibly because `PORT` is static and therefore shared by all of the `MultiEchoServer`  instances that you create.)

Comment: What is your specific reason for binding the server to multiple ports?

Comment: I don't think you want multiple servers on multiple ports.  The standard way to do this is have a single listening thread on one port that launches a new thread to handle each incoming connection.  This is well documented all over the internet.